# Кириллические символы выводятся из mysql вопросительными знаками

Tags: mysql, node.js, кодировка

Имеется mysql база данных, в которой хранятся записи как латиницей, так и кириллицей. Подключение к базе происходит через

```
const iconv = require("iconv-lite")
const { MySQL } = require('mysql-promisify');

const db = new MySQL({
 host: 'xxx',
 user: 'xxx',
 password:'xxx',
 charset: 'utf8_unicode_ci',
 database: 'xxx',
 timeout: 100,
});

(async() => {
var{ results } = await db.query({
    sql: `SELECT * FROM xxx`,
});

console.log(results)// Кириллические символы отображаются в виде вопросительных знаков

Array.prototype.forEach.call(results, result=> {
    var message = iconv.encode(iconv.decode(result['title'], "cp1251"), "utf8").toString();
  console.log(message);//При такой конвертации выводится вместо вопросительных знаков "эээ"
});
})();
```

На данных момент в базе лежат поля с типом TEXT и кодировкой utf8_unicode_ci. Вариации пробовались разные, но никакая не помогла решить проблему.

Comment: дык, `result['title']` и так должен быть в utf8... зачем его декодировать из cp1251?

Comment: По идее, раз хранится в utf 8, то и доставаться должно в utf 8, но тем не менее из базы без декодирования кириллица выводится в виде ???

Comment: не важно, в какой кодировке хранится — сервер сам перекодирует все данные в кодировку, которую запросит клиент... по идее параметр `charset: 'utf8_unicode_ci'` в конструкторе должен как раз и устанавливать кодировку соединения, клиента и результата.  Для уверенности выполни (в той сессии в которой проблемы, а не в клиенте) `SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';`. Ещё возможен вариант, что поля изначально были добавлены в базу в неправильной кодировке.

Comment: Выводит, что у  character_set_filesystem Value = 'binary', у character_set_system Value = 'utf8', у остальных - cp1251

Comment: значит кодировка корректно не устанавливается... можно разобраться, почему пареметр `charset` конструктора не работает корректно... а можно просто выполнить вручную [`SET NAMES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-names.html) после создания соединения...